# How to configure the number of threads to run on slave machines in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How can I control the number of threads running on each jmeter slave machines.
i.e. if I have **300 threads** in total and  **2 slave machines**, I want the load to be distributed evenly on both slave machine -  **150 threads** to run on slave **machine A** & **150 Threads** to run on slave **machine B**.

I have tried running in non gui mode also with the below commands

```
Jmeter  -n -t TESTING.jmx  -R 10.27.30.93 –J 6
```

to make it run on a specific slave server for 6 threads, but its not working.
It invokes the same number of threads saved in the test plan

Answer (score 2):

1. Set "Number of Threads" for Thread Group(s) using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like

   ```
   ${__P(threads,)}
   ```

[image: Thread number as property]

2. Amend your JMeter startup script invocation as follows:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t TESTING.jmx -R 10.27.30.93 –Gthreads=6
   ```

   As per JMeter command-line help:

   ```
   -G, --globalproperty <argument>=<value>
       Define Global properties (sent to servers)
       e.g. -Gport=123
        or -Gglobal.properties
   ```
3. Another option is configure desired number of threads for each remote engine in *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of JMeter installation).

   See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on setting and/or overriding JMeter Properties.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T i tried the 1st approach but i am getting the following error "unknown argument uGthreads=6 errorlevel=1"

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T i used -Gthreads=6 only but it was throwing an error uGthreads=6 i.e u with carrot over it

Comment: Maybe copy-paste issue from StackOverflow. See [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) for reference

Comment: Hi  @Dmitri T  the following command worked.jmeter -n -t TESTING.jmx
 -Gthreads=6 -R 10.27.30.93 ,thanks for your help