# jmeter distributed testing slaves not reading the property when properties are sent with -G option

Tags: jmeter, global-variables, distributed, properties-file, master-slave

I am able to successfully run JMeter in master slave configuration in both GUI and non GUI mode when the user defined variables are hardcoded in the test plan. But now I am trying to set these with properties using the
 -Gglobal.properties option on master where I have the properties defined in the global.properties file.
Then I am using ${__property(concurrent.threads)} function in the User defined variables.

When I run the remote test I see the property being set to the literal "concurrent.threads" and the test fails to run. The jmeter manual for __property reads:

```
If the property value cannot be found, and no default has been supplied, it returns the property name
```

why are the properties not being sent to the slaves, is there a bug in JMeter?

I also tried -Gconcurrent.threads=100 in the command line options and I still get the same behaviour.

Looks like it worked for some other user in 2015 -- 
[How to configure the number of threads to run on slave machines in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809597/how-to-configure-the-number-of-threads-to-run-on-slave-machines-in-jmeter)

Comment: do you run your remote tests in master's GUI mode?

Comment: Thanks for the insight! it worked in non GUI mode!!!

Comment: right, that was not really straightforwardly mentioned in documentation - although quite obvious yet